# socket send error Bad file descriptor (9)

Tags: bitcoind, error

The log file goes back quite a few weeks but this error started to appear today. Any ideas why? [image: errors in log]

Comment: I am seeing that a lot too. I've stopped receiving blockchain information; I don't know if this error is associated with not receiving blockchain information. Any progress on figuring this out?